# Locus circle and equilateral triangle question

Tags: circles, locus

An equilateral triangle of side 25cm circumscribes a circle. Find the radius of the circle.

I drew it out, and tried to create a right angled triangle and perform Pythagoras but it was not right, do you have any idea where I went wrong? Or how to solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: center of circle inscribed in a triangle is intersection of angle bisectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strong hint: The red triangle here has one vertex in the vertex of the black triangle, one vertex where the circle touches the black triangle, and one vertex at the center of the circle.

[image]

The angles in the red triangle are $30^\circ, 60^\circ$ and $90^\circ$. One of the legs is the radius of the circle, and the other leg is half the side of the black triangle.

Comment: So I did this and I used the sine rule to solve it so sin(60)/12.5 * sin(90) and then I gey 0.069... the answer is 7.22. So I'm not sure what to do

Comment: @user639649 Well, first off, this is about the two legs, not the hypotenuse, so $\tan$ is the appropriate one. Second, you don't need any trig. In a $30^\circ-60^\circ-90^\circ$ triangle, the hypotenuse is twice the short leg. Now Pythagoras solves it for you. Finally, $\sin(90^\circ)$ should be $0$ exactly. Are you certain your calculator is set to using degrees?

Comment: (Apparently, even experienced mathematicians can't really keep $\sin$ and $\cos$ straight when they have other things on their minds. $\sin(90^\circ)$ is, of course, $1$. It is $\cos(90^\circ)$ which is $0$.

Comment: That is okay! The point about tan mad me realise I was overcomplicating the question by using sine/cosine rules. I did tan30 * 12.5 = 7.22 ( 2 dp) ! Which is the correct answer.